# How to navigate child Components in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a parent Component that contain several child components that may be called. These child Components may be called or not, they may just need the first child Component as this is a OnePage app.

My parent component looks like this:

[image]

Where the blue area is the common area and the green area is reserved for child Components.

I want to be able to go `Next` if the user wants to.
NOTE: This is not a stepper. The user may proceed to the next child component or not...

I tried to use Routes, but the configured Routes I have look like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/dossier/:dossierId' component={Dossier}></Route>
  <Route path='/' component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

So if I add an extra Route there, it will **change the whole component**, not just the child one.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to just exchange child components in a parent one.

Any ideas or real solutions I can apply? I feel a bit lost here...

Comment: So something like a carousel? What have you tried already? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use react-router-dom in version 6 you have to add following structure to your code ...

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={< Home />} />
      <Route path="/..." element={< yourComponent/>} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

your router-dom-version can you see in your package.json - dependencies

Regards

Jonas